# Why are ActiveX controls on the Insert menu of the developer tab disabled?

Tags: excel, activex, vba

I need to programatically fill in the contents of a combobox that is on a worksheet in my Excel 2007 file from VBA. From some researching it seems this cannot be done with a "Forms Control", I must use an ActiveX version of the combobox.

That's all fine, except on the Insert menu of the Developer Tab in Excel, the only controls that are enabled that I can add are the form versions. All of the ActiveX controls are greyed out and I can't figure out why.

What am I missing? Macros are enabled. I've checked ActiveX security settings and set it to enable everything. Is there some add-in necessary that isn't installed by default?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm running Win7 64bit with 32bit Office 2007.

Comment: Try going into design mode before inserting the control

Comment: I am in design mode. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.  Unprotecting the workbook fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting for View objects.

Office Button > Excel Options > Advanced > Display Options for this workbook

> For objects, show: All

Cheers
Andy

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/insert-illustrations-disabled-grayed-out-excel-2007-a-t3813221p2.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not yet selected a cell in your worksheet.

For some reason the ActiveX controls are greyed out if you don't have a cell selected (even though you draw the control onto the sheet...).

Answer (score -1):

I still have no idea why the ActiveX controls were disabled, but I abandoned my file and created a new one. The controls weren't disabled in my new file.